# I Was on Debian stable - How did I end up on Bullseye?

Tags: debian, upgrade, headless

Maybe a silly question, but a remote server was down for an extended period today. When it came back up, I realized the downtime was apparently due to a system upgrade, from Debian Buster (stable) to Bullseye (testing).

I'm a bit confused, because I am the only superuser on this server, and I have not scheduled any kind of update in some time. I don't run production machines on testing, and I didn't intentionally set the system up to automatically upgrade operating system versions. I do periodically use apt to update and upgrade individual packages, but I certainly did not call for a full release upgrade.

Any obvious configuration settings I might have made to trigger this - for example, changing my apt sources unintentionally etc.? I don't want any more unexpected updates. (It's a headless Minecraft server, for what it's worth, and downtime is bad when people want to play.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a two things which could cause this.  You can find out which by using:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

1. Using a suite instead of a codename:

```
(1) deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ buster main
(2) deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stable main
```

Line `(1)` and `(2)` are equivalent today, but they won't always be.  One day, `stable` will point to `bullseye`.  When that happens, your machine will automatically change too.  If you want control, then use codename `buster`.  Check for the `testing` suite.  That switched from `buster` to `bullseye` on 6 July 2019.

2. Multiple distributions:

```
(1) deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ buster main
(2) deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main
(3) deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ testing main
```

If you have something like what's above, then Debian may see several versions of each package.  The latest version of a package will be selected unless you've set `APT::Default-Release` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` or explicitly pinned priorities in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/`.

---

The next question is why did your `sources.list` have a strange entry?  It could be that you've added a line because you wanted the latest version of a package which was only available in bullseye.  In that case you may have added the line, `apt update` then `apt install -t testing some-package`. But the problem is that unless you delete that line and do another `apt update`, or add a `APT::Default-Release`, you are primed for an upgrade to `testing`,

Another option is 3rd party software.  It's common for software which doesn't exist in Debian's official archive to give you a `*.deb` installer.  I've seen `*.deb` archives include a custom `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` so that you get updates.  It wouldn't be hard for them to say "well I need version X of this dependency, and I know it exists in bullseye, so I'll create a line to add a bullseye repo".  It would by sloppy of them, but not impossible.

---

So how to recover?  There are three options at this point:

1: Complete the upgrade - Easiest/quickest

2: Downgrade - Hardest/Least likely to succeed

3: Re-install - Most reliable/Most downtime

To **Complete the upgrade**, first obviously fix the strange line in your `/etc/apt/sources.list[.d/]`.  Then:

```
# Make everything 'bullseye'
sudo sed -i                  \
  -e 's/buster/bullseye/g'   \
  -e 's/unstable/bullseye/g' \
  -e 's/stable/bullseye/g'   \
  -e 's/testing/bullseye/g'  \
  -e 's/sid/bullseye/g'      \
  /etc/apt/sources.list      \
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*

# Upgrade
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt autoremove
```

Toggle between `upgrade`, `dist-upgrade`, `--fix-broken install` and `autoremove` until `apt` finishes successfully everywhere.

To **downgrade** (and this is likely to fail, I can't stress that enough):

First back everything up.  Then, create `/etc/apt/preferences.d/buster`:

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=buster
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

Then upgrade like we did in step 1

```
sudo sed -i                \
  -e 's/bullseye/buster/g' \
  -e 's/unstable/buster/g' \
  -e 's/stable/buster/g'   \
  -e 's/testing/buster/g'  \
  -e 's/sid/buster/g'      \
  /etc/apt/sources.list    \
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*

# Upgrade
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt autoremove
```

Toggle between `upgrade`, `dist-upgrade`, `--fix-broken install` and `autoremove` until `apt` finishes successfully everywhere.

When you are happy, delete `/etc/apt/preferences.d/buster`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But it looks like what happened is my /etc/apt/sources.list switched from referencing buster or stable explicitly to referencing bullseye.

 I do not know how to check since I did not install etckeeper (I now have) and the old version was overwritten. 

I am pretty sure I did not reference testing or bullseye explicitly.

I would have gone for some inadvertent change as an explanation, but then I saw the original poster's problem was exactly the same as mine.

Unless I am mistaken your answer, despite being excellently written, does not cover that.

Comment: In my case it looks like I added testing as a source at some point (think it was a module needed for Minecraft server, the only reason my Debian box exists!). Something triggered a full distribution update. Running dist-upgrade after explicitly changing all sources to bullseye didn't trigger any action at all - it was already upgraded.

Comment: @dee I think you are asking why your `source.list` went from referencing `buster` to referencing `bullseye`.  It's hard for me to guess, but I *can* say: it was not anything in the official debian archive. Software in the debian archive is strictly reviewed to avoid these kinds of mistakes.  If you are sure no user made the change, then you should suspect 3rd party deb files (Minecraft.deb). Software/scripts only have the opportunity to change `sources.list` when run with root privileges. You give `minecraft.deb` root privilages for only a moment during install.

Comment: Yeah I thought I made an inadvertent mistake but then I saw original poster had exactly the same symptoms so I thought there might be something else.
Only real takeaway is one should always install etckeeper.

Comment: FWIW, I downloaded and inspected `Minecraft.deb` as deployed by Mojang.  I didn't see anything malice in there.  It didn't deploy files to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`, nor did it have any `preinst` or `postinst` control files.  Therefore I don't think `Minecraft.deb` caused it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to this an answer for anyone affected similarly.
I was scratching my head about how I ended up on bullseye, until I spotted:

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/ sid main
deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/ sid main
```

Somehow I'd either absent mindedly added that into `/etc/apt/sources.list` , or wine had with my equally absent minded approval. I specifically wasn't using a standard wine build but the latest unstable to test something out for a project.